# Deploying shiny app to shinyapp.io with a package not on CRAN or Github

Tags: r, github, shiny, rdcomclient, shinyapps

I am trying to deploy my shiny app but it is failing because RDCOMClient is not on CRAN or Github. Well to clarify a version of RDCOMClient is on Github at [here](https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient) but this version does not appear to work with my version of R. I downloaded the binary of the package from [here](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/) and my app works fine locally.

Possible solutions I have seen or thought of are

1. Somehow take the binaries from the non-github address and put them on my own github then load the library from my own Github account to have my app deploy properly.
2. Rollback my version of R to be compatible with the RDCOMClient found at omegahat's github
3. Find a different library than RDCOMClient to work in its place.

Option #1 - I am unsure of how to put the binaries on Github since R looks for a specific folder/file structure when it pulls in packages from Github.

Option #2 - This seems pretty straight-forward but I worry that some of the other packages or code may not work with an earlier version. Also if someone could link to how to rollback your version of R it would be much appreciated.

Option #3 - I am using RDCOMClient to connect to Outlook and launch a draft email. If someone knows of another package that does something similar to this then this would be a viable solution.

I am of course open to other solutions to this problem and anything that could help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This binary looks like one for Windows.  So are you on Windows too?  According to http://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/appendix.html#default-system-packages, shinyapps.io is running on linux machine.  So I don't think this binary works there.  Also, I tried to install RDCOMClient on my linux machine from http://www.omegahat.net, but did not succeed.  My guess is that there are some challenges to make this package run on linux machine.

Comment: Thank you Kota! Do you know of any r package that would run on linux machines that can connect to Microsoft Outlook and launch an email draft?

Comment: I don't know (does not mean there is none).  If you want to connect to MS Outlook, then don't you need the machine to have outlook installed?  I don't think you can do that easily on shinyapp.io?

Comment: So I have rolled back to an earlier version of R and I am able to load the library from github now when I deploy it to shinyapps.io but as you mention this is creating further problems. Anyway thank you Kota Mori for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729735/deploy-shiny-app-on-shinyapp-io-with-package-in-private-organization-repo/52281760#52281760)