# Deploy shiny app on shinyapp.io with package in private organization repo

Tags: github, deployment, repository, rstudio, shinyapps

I'm trying to deploy a shiny app to the shinyapps.io server, but keep getting an error relating to a custom-built package that is hosted in a private github repo owned by our organization (note that I have replaced the actual name of the package, company name, and private repo name in the error below):

```
error: Building package: [PACKAGE NAME]
################################ Begin Task Log 
################################ 
################################# End Task Log 
################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 530176316 failed: Error building 
image: Error fetching [PACKAGE NAME] (1.0.2) source. Error accessing GitHub 
repository ORGANIZATION/PRIVATE_REPO. HTTP 404: Not Found
```

I know the repo link is good, because installing via `devtools::install_github("ORGANIZATION/PRIVATE_REPO, auth_token = token` works.
I'm an admin for the organization page, and also made sure that `token` has both repo and admin:org scope.

I've also made sure to tick "Private Repository Access" in my shinyapps.io account page as stated [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204536558-Enabling-use-of-private-packages-on-github-com).

Anyone have any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong??

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you have authorized shinyapps.io to use your github profile? See Account > Profile > Scroll down to connect with github.

Answer (score 5):

Create an `.Rprofile` file in your project folder that you would intend to deploy.

You would need to set that repo options in the `.Rprofile`. and add your private github link. Something like

```
# A sample .Rprofile file with two different package repositories.
local({
  r <- getOption("repos")
  r["CRAN"] <- "https://cran.rstudio.com/"
  r["mycompany"] <- "http://rpackages.mycompany.com/"
  options(repos = r)
})
```

This is well explained here. [Package management in RStudio Connect](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/226871467-Package-management-in-RStudio-Connect).

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to enable private access to the repo in the shinyapps.io dashboard as shown [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204536558-Enabling-use-of-private-packages-on-github-com)

[image: private github repo shinyapps]

But you also need to give the proper permissions to the organization from github -> settings -> applications

[image: github applicatons settings]

Select shinyapps from the applications list

[image: select shinyapps application]

And then grant access to the specific organization

[image: grant org access]

And you are done!
`rsconnect` will automatically detect the source of the repo, provided it as installed with the `auth_token` parameter using `devtools::install_github`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, I found the above answer to allow for specific corporate repositories, not installing from a private github repo. For that, [this link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204536558-Enabling-use-of-private-packages-on-github-com) has this to say:

Go to Account >> Profile, then under github LINK the accounts, and allow private repo access.