# Deploy app to shinyapps.io that depends on custom package which itself has dependencies

Tags: r, deployment, shinyapps, rsconnect

I would like to deploy a shiny app to [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/) 
but I keep failing to publish it all in all for several months now :-(

Could someone please explain to me step-by-step what I need to do for the specific setup outlined below?

### Setup

- the app depends on a custom package that lives in a private GitHub repo
- I do not have a full-fledged R package repo that is accessible by RStudio Connect in order to install the custom package but would like to install it from GitHub
- a `.Rprofile` file lives in the root directory of the project that I'm trying to publish and it contains

```
local({
  r <- getOption("repos")
  r["CRAN"] <- "https://cran.rstudio.com/"
  r["mycompany"] <- "https://github.com/rappster/mypkg/"
  options(repos = r)
})
```

- the `tar.gz` build of the custom package lives in `/opt/r-packages/<pkg-name>/<git-commit-hashkey>.tar.gz`
- a `gcfg` file lives in `/etc/rstudio-connect/rstudio-connect.gcfg` and it only contains `SourcePackageDir = "opt/r-packages"`
- the custom package has itself a number of dependencies that are all available on CRAN
- the code for the shiny app lives in several files in the root dir of the project which currently corresponds to the custom's package project (since I thought this would be the easiest to make publishing work), but I could also put it in its own RStudio/R project if that would help

### Due diligence

I've read

- [Deploy shiny app on shinyapp.io with package in private organization repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729735/deploy-shiny-app-on-shinyapp-io-with-package-in-private-organization-repo)
- [Package management in RStudio Connect](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/226871467-Package-management-in-RStudio-Connect)
- [RStudio Connect configuration options](https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/1.5.4/admin/appendix-configuration.html#appendix-configuration-server)

but wasn't able to get things working.

### RStudio Connect deployment error that I'm getting

```
<...>
[2019-02-05T11:50:16.877574592+0000] Building R package: mypkg (0.0.2.9002)
/mnt/packages/build /mnt
Warning in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
* installing to library ‘/opt/R/3.5.1/lib/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘mypkg’ ...
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘philentropy’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘climater’
* removing ‘/opt/R/3.5.1/lib/R/library/mypkg’GET /v1/tasks/?filter=account_id:113102&filter=parent_id:584709513&count=100&offset=0 590ms
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
----- Deployment error -----
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 584709513 failed: Error building image: Error building mypkg (0.0.2.9002). Build exited with non-zero status: 1

----- Error stack trace -----
3: stop(status$error, call. = FALSE)
2: client$waitForTask(taskId, quiet)
1: rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "C:/Users/janko/Dropbox (Personal)/Code/R/Packages/_Dev/mypkg", 
       appFileManifest = "C:/Users/janko/AppData/Local/Temp/6d2a-63b4-2877-4884", 
       account = "janko-thyson", server = "shinyapps.io", appName = "mypkg", 
       appId = 585041, launch.browser = function(url) {
           message("Deployment completed: ", url)
       }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE, 
           ignoredFiles = <...>), 
       logLevel = "verbose")
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 584709513 failed: Error building image: Error building mypkg (0.0.2.9002). Build exited with non-zero status: 1
Execution halted
```

Does that mean I need to build all of my package's dependencies and also put it under `opt/<pkg-dependency-name>/<git-commit-hashkey>.tar.gz`?

Sorry in case this is a duplicate or seems to be a bit unstructured/verbose, but my head is completely swirling trying to get this to work and I have no clue where to start with troubleshooting...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am also trying to install a package Shiny app on shinyapps.io. It depends on 2 packages only on GitHub. I get the same issue as you.

Comment: The error in you log, shows that a couple packages are not in your NAMESPACE. You should review the source code for "mypkg" and:  include `import(philentropy)` in your NAMESPACE file ; consider also to add `Depends: philentropy` in your DESCRIPTION file.

Answer (score 0):

## Deploy shiny app using custom package with RStudio

- Use `renv` in your app project
- Generate a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) in GitHub
- Modify the `.Rprofile` (is in your project directory) to show this:

```r
source("renv/activate.R")
local({
  r <- getOption("repos")
  r["CRAN"] <- "https://cran.rstudio.com/"
  r["mycompany"] <- "https://github.com/<your_user>/<your_repo>/"
  options(repos = r)
})
```

- Within your project, open the R terminal and install your package:

```r
devtools::install_github("<my_user>/<my_repo>",
    auth_token = "<paste_your_token_here>",
    upgrade = "never") #this is optional, 
# but since you are using renv, you may want to conserve 
# your environment
```

This will install your package in the `renv`

**IMPORTANT**: don't include the previous line in the source code you're going to upload to shiny.io or similar [Read about it](https://groups.google.com/g/shinyapps-users/c/uX22Tu_veOM)

- Publish your app.

After you've done this, *rsconnect* should be able to read your packages from your source code and upload them from your *renv*. Actually, the first time shiny.io build my package, there was a time out and didn't upload the app. But, it installed my custom package in its environment and the second time I tried to upload the app, it worked.

**NOTE**: In my case, my package was in a public github repository. Haven't tried with private repos, but I know there's an option in *shiny.io* that connects the server to the private repositories. I think you will also need to configure your personal access token so it can be use to read private repos.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would equally work for a private repo but, to use a public GitHub repo, just simply:

1. Unload the package:

```
detach("package:mypkg", unload = TRUE)
```

2. Reinstall the package from GitHub on your local machine:

```
devtools::install_github("https://github.com/myorg/mypkg", upgrade = TRUE)
```

3. Click publish.

Shiny will figure out the rest.