# unable to deploy shiny app to shinyapp.io (cannot access github repo for pacakge dependencies?)

Tags: r, github, shiny, shinyapps

I wanted to create an accessible html page of my interactive heatmap from Interactive Complex heatmap and the following is my code;
the running of app is successful but the deployment is not
i get the following error from the code below

> Warning: unable to access index for repository https://github.com/jokergoo/InteractiveComplexHeatmap.git/src/contrib:
> cannot open URL 'https://github.com/jokergoo/InteractiveComplexHeatmap.git/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
> Warning: unable to access index for repository https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap.git/src/contrib:
> cannot open URL 'https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap.git/src/contrib/PACKAGES

I understand that if i use install_github() from devtools i dont have to set the URL under options repos=()
However, when i am currently unable to reinstall Interactive Complex Heatmap using install_github() due to "non zero exit status" error; therefore i am setting the direct URL for rsconnect to access.

App.R Code below:

```
options(repos = c("CRAN" = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  "BioC" = "https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/bioc/","InteractiveComplexHeatmap"="https://github.com/jokergoo/InteractiveComplexHeatmap.git","ComplexHeatmap"="https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap.git"))

library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(InteractiveComplexHeatmap)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(shiny)
library(rsconnect)
colAnn <- HeatmapAnnotation(df=my_sample_col,which = "col",col=genotypecolors)
rowAnn <- HeatmapAnnotation(df=mygenecol2,which = "row",col=themecolors)
heatmap=Heatmap(counts, name = "Z-score counts", col = myCol,column_title = "%s",
                cluster_rows = FALSE,show_column_dend = FALSE,row_split = mygenecol2,column_split = my_sample_col,row_title_rot = 0,column_km = 1,
                left_annotation = rowAnn,row_names_gp =gpar(fontsize=2))
ht=draw(heatmap)
htShiny(ht)

library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(
    InteractiveComplexHeatmapOutput()
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
    makeInteractiveComplexHeatmap(input, output, session, ht)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
deployApp("C:/Users/K/Desktop/appdir/myapp")
```

Hope to get any advice please! I dont understand why rsconnect is unable to link to the github package source URL. I am very lost and i dont know where to edit... Please help!
Thank you!

App works fine lcoally btw.

Comment: [similar problem] [similar problem]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729735/deploy-shiny-app-on-shinyapp-io-with-package-in-private-organization-repo
may be you will find this question helpfull